# Why is Padrino rendering my views as escaped text?

Tags: rendering, padrino, slim

I am using `slim` as my rendering engine.  Here is my application.slim

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Hello

    body
        = yield
```

Here is my view ("views/welcome/index.slim")

```
h1 Hello
```

The application.slim is being rendered correctly, but I see "< h1>Hello< /h1>" on the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  You have to use `==` when rendering a partial if you don't want it escaped.  Can't believe I didn't see that in the docs.